# not able to solve java session asking to log in again

Tags: java, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [not able to solve java session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982028/not-able-to-solve-java-session)

```
    HttpSession sess = request.getSession();       
     String username=request.getParameter("firstname");
     String password=request.getParameter("pwd");
     boolean flag;
     if(username!=null && password!=null){
      flag=checking.check(username, password);  //here i check if user exists in //the data base
     }else{
     flag=false;
     }
     if(flag){
     put2.sessionAttr(username,password,sess); // here i call a java class through bean put2 and set attributes to the session
     response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
     }
```

in the end i add attributes to the session i set an attribute of username..

after closing the browser without logging out i enter the same url and call the following jsp through ajax

```
HttpSession ses=request.getSession();
       if(ses.getAttribute("username")==null){
       out.print("falseconfirm");      

        out.flush();

       }else{
       out.print("trueconfirm");

        out.flush();
       }
```

but the session seems have no attributes at all..
so i have to enter username and password again..

Comment: Why are you asking this again?

Answer (score 0):

Closing the browser means you lost the session. Opening a new browser always creates a new session and hence you are seeing this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you are closing the browser the session will automatically cleared and you can't access that session no more.